# Sufficient condition on integrator that Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function on $[0,1]$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\alpha$ be nondecreasing on $[0,1]$. Then Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function is well defined with respect to the integrator $\alpha$.

I was wondering if the following assertion is true:

> (1) If $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable on $[0,1],$ then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ with respect to the measure induced by $\alpha$.
>
> (2) Do we need additional hypotheses on $\alpha$ for guaranteeing the above assertion? For example, $\alpha$ is right-continuous.

I would be grateful if you give any comment for my question.

Comment: @G. Chiusole  Certainly **not** a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: Monotone functions on the open interval $(0,1)$ need not be bounded, let alone be of bounded variation, so in general the Riemann-Steltjes integral will not exist. In order for the question to make sense, you may want to consider functions on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @uniquesolution  Thanks a lot! I corrected it.

Comment: @uniquesolution How so? It boils down to the question "Does Riemann integrable imply Lebesgue integrable"

Comment: @G.Chiusole Thanks for your comment. For $\alpha(x)=x$ on [0,1], the assertion is true. Note that in this case, $\alpha$ is continuous.

Comment: @04170706 ah yes, my bad.

Comment: Look at "WHEEDEN, Richard – Measure and Integral 2nd ed".

Comment: @lzralbu Thanks a lot. I will check it later, since I don’t have the book now.